# How to unit test big list?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin

I have this result as list in my service I wrote this unit test

```
@SpringBootTest(
  classes = [CmsApplication::class],
  webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
internal class IngredientsServiceImplTest {
  @Autowired
  lateinit var restTemplate: TestRestTemplate


  @Test
  fun getIngredients() {
    val result = restTemplate.getForObject("/ingredients", GetIngredientsQuery.Data::class.java);
    assertNotNull(result)
    assertTrue(result.ingredients!!.isNotEmpty())
    assertEquals(result.ingredients!!.size, 512)
    val first: GetIngredientsQuery.Ingredient = result.ingredients!![0]
    assertEquals(first.displayName,"Salz")
    assertEquals(first.image,"/api/consumer/ingredient/salt/image")
    assertEquals(first.popular,false)
    assertEquals(first.staple,true)
  }
}
```

here the thing is the list is 512 in size
I thought I need to assertEqual all items in list
as you can see I do that with the first element
any suggestions or maybe this test is enough?

this is the method

```
override suspend fun getIngredients(locale: String?, supportedApiVersion: Int?): GetIngredientsQuery.Data? {
    return this.apollo.buildApolloClient().query(GetIngredientsQuery(this.initRequestConfig(locale, supportedApiVersion)))
        .execute().data
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes has the correct `toString()` method defined you simply can do
`assertEquals(expected, actual)` and it's not necessary to loop through all the values in the list.

The idea is you create an expected result that should be the same as you expect from your rest (the actual).

It's not necessary all of those `assertNotNull()`, `assertTrue()`, if you do the `assertEquals()` and there is an empty list or null it will crash anyways so you can delete these asserts.

Pd: Why you want to test 512 items? Tests should be fast, so not sure if having 512 items is worth for you to ensure that your code works.

### Example

```
@Test
fun test() {
  val actual = restTemplate.getForObject("/ingredients", GetIngredientsQuery.Data::class.java)

  val expected = listOf<Ingredients>(....)
  assertEquals(expected, actual)
}
```

Comment: okay thanks a lot ,this brightened my mind

Comment: Ingredients is not a class, do I need to create it and add items>?

Comment: What's the name of the class? Can you put in your question the data class?

Comment: The idea is you create an expected result that should be the same as you expect from your rest (the actual). this is the point I need expected list ,so waht do I need to add 512 elements to get equal as true?

Comment: I added the method

Comment: Can't you mock the response? Why are 512 items?

Comment: it ried but it says method should be suspend too

Comment: Can you post the full class of RestTemplate?

Comment: val apollo: ApolloClientConfig = mockk();

    val ingredientsService = IngredientsServiceImpl(apollo);


    @Test
    suspend fun getIngredients() {
        val result = ingredientsService.getIngredients("en",1)
        
    }

Comment: Itried this one it's okay i think